# Validate A token using spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Please i need help on Spring security...

Client provides username and password to the application, it returns a token so they can access other resources. the client provides the token via header.
The application validates the token to verify if the client has access to resources.

Please Note: The application is a RESTFUL application so no form of UI/UX.Just pure JSON

Lastly, The application configuration is Java based configuration not XML..

Comment: so what is you question?

Comment: can you please explain?

Comment: Albert Pinto , trying to build an app using spring...users make a request with token.the app validate the token..my problem is how to go about validate before processing the request..if the user does not have access,it should return a json contain 'access denied'

Comment: Can you please tell me who is generating the token?

Comment: The application generates it initally..

Answer (score 0):

For our application we use an in house encryptor/de-cryptor(it is a business requirement). We may migrate to oauth in future. We have build a Spring rest webservice without using Spring security.

User enter their credentials in login screen in UI which calls a REST service to authenticate the request. We have written a java interceptor to intercept the request and call a service to validate user and then if the user is authenticated then to call encryptor to generate a token. The token is passed on to client and is saved in browser db.

After the successful authentication any subsequent webservice call from UI will have the token as part of the request header and decryptor will decrypt the token to validate the user.

Comment: if you want there are lot of sample spring security examplese avsailable online or in GIT

Comment: its worth setting up and having a look